# Gitlab Runner CI/CD Cannot find cache

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a single runner with a concurrency of 4 set in the config.toml. I have a global cache settings

```
cache:
    key:
        files:
            - pnpm-lock.yaml
    paths:
        - node_modules/
        - .pnpm-store
    policy: pull # prevent subsequent jobs from modifying cache
```

And a .pre job to run this:

```
.node:install:
    image: node:18
    cache:
        - key:
              files:
                  - pnpm-lock.yaml
          paths:
              - node_modules/
              - .pnpm-store
          policy: pull-push
    stage: .pre
    script:
        - npm i -g pnpm
        - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
        - pnpm install
```

Then all the other jobs should basically pick up on this cache an do their thing. However, sometimes I get jobs that fail becuase they cannot find node_modules which makes no sense as another job (either parallel or a previous stage) is able to find them (`ls -al` and I see them) and the cache keys are the same that they use for extracting.

I tried already clearing the caches as I thought the issue might have been some bad cache. However even afterwards I produced a cache in the install job which had all the artifacts and had a key of XYZ, job A took XYZ and had node_modules and job B took XYZ but had no cached resources. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Adding output logs

Install job:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.6.1 (f5da3c5a)
  on Rig1SZBG L1fhyq-4n, system ID: r_VS0yOcR6noaS
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:03
Using Docker executor with image node:18 ...
Pulling docker image node:18 ...
Using docker image sha256:219cd50149ac6d8c205c86927e0252bf16490f89461847b7d9120a1f5a477594 for node:18 with digest node@sha256:a17842484dd30af97540e5416c9a62943c709583977ba41481d601ecffb7f31b ...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on runner-l1fhyq-4n-project-52299220-concurrent-0 via fb831fda7795...
Getting source from Git repository
00:12
$ rm -f /builds/*/*/.git/shallow.lock
Fetching changes with git depth set to 1...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/terazza/1086960857/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out e073944d as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:27
Checking cache for 0_pnpm-lock-71f6c89a10f6a9474a9519b5740bac11d32582ec-1-protected...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:11
Using docker image sha256:219cd50149ac6d8c205c86927e0252bf16490f89461847b7d9120a1f5a477594 for node:18 with digest node@sha256:a17842484dd30af97540e5416c9a62943c709583977ba41481d601ecffb7f31b ...
$ npm i -g pnpm
added 1 package in 1s
1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
$ pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
$ pnpm install
...
Done in 8.4s
Saving cache for successful job
01:10
Creating cache 0_pnpm-lock-71f6c89a10f6a9474a9519b5740bac11d32582ec-1-protected...
node_modules/: found 133721 matching artifact files and directories 
.pnpm-store: found 85237 matching artifact files and directories 
No URL provided, cache will not be uploaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally. 
Created cache
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

Lint  (successful job):

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.6.1 (f5da3c5a)
  on Rig1SZBG L1fhyq-4n, system ID: r_VS0yOcR6noaS
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:03
Using Docker executor with image node:18 ...
Pulling docker image node:18 ...
Using docker image sha256:219cd50149ac6d8c205c86927e0252bf16490f89461847b7d9120a1f5a477594 for node:18 with digest node@sha256:a17842484dd30af97540e5416c9a62943c709583977ba41481d601ecffb7f31b ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-l1fhyq-4n-project-52299220-concurrent-0 via fb831fda7795...
Getting source from Git repository
00:06
$ rm -f /builds/*/*/.git/shallow.lock
Fetching changes with git depth set to 1...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/terazza/1086960857/.git/
Checking out e073944d as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Removing .husky/_/
Removing .pnpm-store/
Removing node_modules/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:29
Checking cache for 0_pnpm-lock-71f6c89a10f6a9474a9519b5740bac11d32582ec-1-protected...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
02:01
Using docker image sha256:219cd50149ac6d8c205c86927e0252bf16490f89461847b7d9120a1f5a477594 for node:18 with digest node@sha256:a17842484dd30af97540e5416c9a62943c709583977ba41481d601ecffb7f31b ...
$ ls -al
total 1216
drwxrwxrwx 11 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:21 .
drwxrwxrwx  8 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:19 ..
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root     245 Nov 27 22:19 .editorconfig
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root      13 Nov 27 22:19 .eslintignore
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    5981 Nov 27 22:19 .eslintrc.json
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:21 .git
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root     980 Nov 27 22:19 .gitignore
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    1772 Nov 27 22:19 .gitlab-ci.yml
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:21 .husky
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root      55 Nov 27 22:19 .npmrc
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root       3 Nov 27 22:19 .nvmrc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Nov 27 21:08 .pnpm-store
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root     138 Nov 27 22:19 .prettierignore
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root     138 Nov 27 22:19 .prettierrc
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root     138 Nov 27 22:19 .prettierrc.json
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:19 .vscode
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    3231 Nov 27 22:19 README.md
drwxrwxrwx  8 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:19 apps
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:19 ci
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root      98 Nov 27 22:19 jest.config.ts
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root      88 Nov 27 22:19 jest.preset.js
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:19 node_modules
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    2147 Nov 27 22:19 nx.json
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    6738 Nov 27 22:19 package.json
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:19 packages
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root    4096 Nov 27 22:19 plugins
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root 1049962 Nov 27 22:19 pnpm-lock.yaml
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root   73561 Nov 27 22:19 swagger-spec.json
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    2135 Nov 27 22:19 tsconfig.base.json
...
Saving cache for successful job
00:00
Not uploading cache 0_pnpm-lock-71f6c89a10f6a9474a9519b5740bac11d32582ec-1-protected due to policy
```

A cdk job that ran in a stage after failed as shown below

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.6.1 (f5da3c5a)
  on Rig1SZBG L1fhyq-4n, system ID: r_VS0yOcR6noaS
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:03
Using Docker executor with image node:18 ...
Pulling docker image node:18 ...
Using docker image sha256:219cd50149ac6d8c205c86927e0252bf16490f89461847b7d9120a1f5a477594 for node:18 with digest node@sha256:a17842484dd30af97540e5416c9a62943c709583977ba41481d601ecffb7f31b ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-l1fhyq-4n-project-52299220-concurrent-0 via fb831fda7795...
Getting source from Git repository
00:07
$ rm -f /builds/*/*/.git/shallow.lock
Fetching changes with git depth set to 1...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/terazza/1086960857/.git/
Checking out e073944d as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Removing .pnpm-store/
Removing dist/
Removing node_modules/
Removing tmp/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:25
Checking cache for 0_pnpm-lock-71f6c89a10f6a9474a9519b5740bac11d32582ec-1-protected...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
....
$ npx nx deploy infra -c $CI_ENVIRONMENT_TIER
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: nx@17.1.3
 >  NX   Could not find Nx modules in this workspace.
   Have you run npm/yarn install?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

Comment: Can you show the _exact_ output of the job log, including the runner/job setup and specifically the parts of the logs that show the [attempted] restoration of the cache at the beginning of the job and the end of the install job that creates (pushes) the cache? The output will help provide necessary information on what runners you're using and how they're configured, as well as what might be going wrong in the cache restoration or cache push process.

Comment: @sytech added it there. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm. Nothing obvious pops out at me. The cache appears to be saved/restored successfully. I don't think you're running into any of the common cache mismatch issues, unless you're using the same cache key in some other job that is overriding the cache contents. In the case of your failing job due to missing `nx`, my first instinct would be to double check that your install job actually installed `nx@17.1.3` and that its absence from the cache is actually unexpected.

Comment: Looking into this from a NodeJS/Nx perspective, maybe the solution here is to make sure you are also caching your `.nx` directory. Also, if you are installing `nx` globally, that may also prevent it from being present in your cached `./node_modules`. I'm not a JS dev, so maybe you'll see something I don't. See also: [updating global nx](https://nx.dev/recipes/installation/update-global-installation#update-your-global-nx-installation) and the relevant [code that invokes the error message](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/7f404ad72064d50b139f327c728033d6ec2ff8fd/packages/nx/bin/nx.ts#L107C1-L109)

Comment: Thats the thing - I run all my command via nx (so event the lint job was then `npx nx run lint` . Plus running via npx (to my understanding) should download the module and run it, so not having it installed should not be an issue. @sytech ..plus there are no other pipelines or runners active